# asp.net core 3.1 accountcontroller missing when creating new project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

when I create a new project asp.net core 3.1 with Visual Studio with Individual User Accounts selected.

I can't find the Account Controller folder. There is an Areas folder but almost empty

Identity is working but where are the codes?

Answer (score 1):

To add Identity scaffolding to a project, read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli#scaffold-identity-into-an-empty-project

However for .Net 3.1, you’ll need to add these via NuGet and select the 3.x.x versions, else dotnet will try to install the latest .Net 6 which is incompatible with .Net3.1…

Also, having done all that, you get the Area/Identity/Pages/Account folder with more .cshtml files.  But still don't see the AccountController in the Controllers folder.

It turns out the code for each operation is in the .cs files for each of the views in the Account folder, per Razor page paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

[You are looking for scaffold identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)